# "Too late for "-C" option" error With Perl and Shell scripts

Tags: java, html, xml, perl, nlp

I have a jar application that has several functions, one of which is to convert from HTML to XML. When I try to run a simple command such as:

```
java -jar lt4el-cmd.jar send -l en "l2:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_computer"
```

I get the following errors:

```
ERROR [Thread-1]: html2base/html2base-wrapper.sh: Too late for "-C" option at html2base/html2xml.pl line 1.
/tmp/lpc.30872.html: failed 
cat: /tmp/lpc.30872.xml: No such file or directory
 (LpcControl.java:229)
ERROR [Thread-1]: ana2ont/ana2ont.sh ${lang}: -:1: parser error : Document is empty
-:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
Tokenization/tagging failed
^
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
-:1: parser error : Document is empty
unable to parse -
 (LpcControl.java:229)
ERROR [Thread-1]: Error in conversion: Error running conversion script (ana2ont/ana2ont.sh ${lang}): 6 (AppInterface.java:159)
```

This is the `html2base-wrapper.sh` script which seems to be where the first error occurs.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "check" ]; then
    . common.sh
    check_binary perl || exit 1
    check_perl_module HTML::TreeBuilder || exit 1
    check_perl_module XML::LibXML || exit 1
    check_binary tidy || exit 1
    check_binary xmllint || exit 1
    check_binary xsltproc || exit 1
    exit
fi

cat >"$TMPDIR/lpc.$$.html"
html2base/html2base.sh -d html2base/LT4ELBase.dtd -x html2base/LT4ELBase.xslt -t "$TMPDIR/lpc.$$.html" >&2
cat "$TMPDIR/lpc.$$.xml";
rm -f "$TMPDIR"/lpc.$$.{ht,x}ml
```

And the `html2base.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Sample script for automated HTML -> XML conversion
#
# Miroslav Spousta <spousta@ufal.mff.cuni.cz>
# $Id: html2base.sh 462 2008-03-17 08:37:14Z qiq $

basedir=`dirname $0`;

# constants
HTML2XML_BIN=${basedir}/html2xml.pl
ICONV_BIN=iconv
TIDY_BIN=tidy
XMLLINT_BIN=xmllint
XSLTPROC_BIN=xsltproc
DTDPARSE_BIN=dtdparse
TMPDIR=/tmp

# default values
VERBOSE=0
ENCODING=
TIDY=0
VALIDATE=0
DTD=${basedir}/LT4ELBase.dtd
XSLT=${basedir}/LT4ELBase.xslt

usage()
{
        echo "usage: html2base.sh [options] file(s)"
        echo "XML -> HTML conversion script."
        echo
        echo "  -e, --encoding=charset  Convert input files from encoding to UTF-8 (none)"
        echo "  -d, --dtd=file      DTD to be used for conversion and validation ($DTD)"
        echo "  -x, --xslt=file     XSLT to be applied after conversion ($XSLT)"
        echo "  -t, --tidy      Run HTMLTidy on input HTML files"
        echo "  -a, --validate      Validate output XML files"
        echo "  -v, --verbose       Be verbose"
        echo "  -h, --help      Print this usage"
    exit 1;
}

OPTIONS=`getopt -o e:d:x:tahv -l encoding:,dtd:,xlst,tidy,validate,verbose,help -n 'convert.sh' -- "$@"`
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    usage;
fi
eval set -- "$OPTIONS"
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
    -e | --encoding)    ENCODING=$2; shift 2 ;;
    -d | --dtd)     DTD=$2; shift 2 ;;
    -x | --xslt)        XSLT=$2; shift 2 ;;
    -t | --tidy)        TIDY=1; shift 1;;
    -a | --validate)    VALIDATE=1; shift 1;;
    -v | --verbose)     VERBOSE=1; shift 1 ;;
    -h | --help)        usage; shift 1 ;;
    --) shift ; break ;;
    *) echo "Internal error!" ; echo $1; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    usage;
fi

DTD_XML=`echo "$DTD"|sed -e 's/\.dtd/.xml/'`
if [ "$VERBOSE" -eq 1 ]; then
    VERBOSE=--verbose
else
    VERBOSE=
fi

# create $DTD_XML if necessary
if [ ! -f "$DTD_XML" ]; then
    if ! $DTDPARSE_BIN $DTD -o $DTD_XML 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "cannot run dtdparse, cannot create $DTD_XML";
        exit 1;
    fi;
fi

# process file by file

total=0
nok=0
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    file=$1;
    if [ -n "$VERBOSE" ]; then
        echo "Processing $file..."
    fi
    f="$file";
    result=0;
    if [ -n "$ENCODING" ]; then
        $ICONV_BIN -f "$ENCODING" -t utf-8 "$f" -o "$file.xtmp"
        result=$?
        error="encoding error"
        f=$file.xtmp
    fi
    if [ "$result" -eq 0 ]; then
        if [ "$TIDY" = '1' ]; then
            $TIDY_BIN --force-output 1 -q -utf8 >"$file.xtmp2" "$f" 2>/dev/null
            f=$file.xtmp2
        fi
        out=`echo $file|sed -e 's/\.x\?html\?$/.xml/'`
        if [ "$out" = "$file" ]; then
            out="$out.xml"
        fi
        $HTML2XML_BIN --simplify-ws $VERBOSE $DTD_XML -o "$out" "$f"
        result=$?
        error="failed"
    fi
    if [ "$result" -eq 0 ]; then
        $XSLTPROC_BIN --path `dirname $DTD` $XSLT "$out" |$XMLLINT_BIN --noblanks --format -o "$out.tmp1" -
        result=$?
        error="failed"
        mv "$out.tmp1" "$out"
        if [ "$result" -eq 0 -a "$VALIDATE" = '1' ]; then
            tmp=`dirname $file`/$DTD
            delete=0
            if [ ! -f $tmp ]; then
                cp $DTD $tmp
                delete=1
            fi
            $XMLLINT_BIN --path `dirname $DTD` --valid --noout "$out"
            result=$?
            error="validation error"
            if [ "$delete" -eq 1 ]; then
                rm -f $tmp
            fi
        fi
    fi
    if [ "$result" -eq 0 ]; then
        if [ -n "$VERBOSE" ]; then
            echo "OK"
        fi
    else
        echo "$file: $error "
        nok=`expr $nok + 1`
    fi
    total=`expr $total + 1`
    rm -f $file.xtmp $file.xtmp2
    shift;
done
if [ -n "$VERBOSE" ]; then
    echo
    echo "Total: $total, failed: $nok"
fi
```

And the beginning part of the html2xml.pl file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -W -C

# Simple HTML to XML (subset of XHTML) conversion tool. Should always produce a
# valid XML file according to the output DTD file specified.
#
# Miroslav Spousta <spousta@ufal.mff.cuni.cz>
# $Id: html2xml.pl 461 2008-03-09 09:49:42Z qiq $

use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::Element;
use HTML::Entities;
use XML::LibXML;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
```

I can't seem to figure where the problem is. And what exactly does `ERROR [Thread-1]` mean?
Thanks

Comment: `ERROR [Thread-1]`  Probable means error in thread 1

Comment: The first error is in html2base/html2xml.pl surely?

Comment: Are you saying that or you are asking? @ChrisTurner

Comment: I'm asking - it's the cause of the first error message in your output, but you're ascribing it to html2base-wrapper.sh

Comment: I'm not really sure. But I've added part of the `html2xml.pl` file to the question for further analysis. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was from the the `html2xml.pl` script as other users rightly mentioned. I'm running ubuntu 16.04.2 system which comes with a default perl 5.22 version. And as this [post](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL5OPT) mentions, using the `-C` option (as from `perl 5.10.1`) on the `#!` line requires you to also specify it on the command line at execution time, which I wasn't sure how to do because I was running a jar file. I installed [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/), instead, which I used to get an earlier version of perl and modified my perl script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/path/to/perlbrew/perl -W -C

# Simple HTML to XML (subset of XHTML) conversion tool. Should always produce a
# valid XML file according to the output DTD file specified.
#
# Miroslav Spousta <spousta@ufal.mff.cuni.cz>
# $Id: html2xml.pl 461 2008-03-09 09:49:42Z qiq $
```

[This](https://perlbrew.pl/Perlbrew-In-Shell-Scripts.html) might also come in handy in setting up shell scripts when using perlbrew.

Thanks for the efforts in contribution.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from having `-C` on the shebang (`#!`) line of a Perl script, but not passing the `-C` to `perl`. This type of error happens when someone does

```
perl html2base/html2xml.pl ...
```

instead of

```
html2base/html2xml.pl ...
```

Comment: I just found that the option: `-C` in the perl script gives errors in recent versions of perl. Is there any way to work around that giving the fact that I'm running it from a compiled jar file? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you could use the fix I provided in my answer. (Note that the only change in Perl is that is started detecting a bug that already existed in the caller.)

Comment: This command: `java -jar lt4el-cmd.jar send -l en . . .` calls the perl script and every other library it needs. How do I fix that since I'm not running `perl html2base/html2xml.pl` at the command line? Thanks

Comment: no, the java code isn't calling the perl script directly - it's calling html2base-wrapper.sh. And that's running html2base/html2base.sh which I'm guessing runs html2base/html2xml.pl or maybe it runs another script which runs it. You'll have to dig around in the various scripts to work out what is running what.

Comment: You could try setting -C with http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL5OPTvbut that could affect other Perl scripts adversely

Comment: @ysth I tried to go through that site, but it seems confusing to me. Could you explain what you meant by setting -C.

Comment: You're asking us what the problem is with a file you still haven't shown us.

Comment: Sorry, messed up that link.  http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL5OPT

Comment: @ikegami I've added all the shell scripts, now, which are present in the working folder.

Comment: Hum. That should work fine. What OS are you using? What's the output of `set | grep ^PERL`

Comment: @ikegami Ubuntun 16.04 on a virtual machine. The command gave no output.